# Ngrx Selectors Returning Initial State

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am new to NgRx and my selectors are returning the blank initial states, rather than using the data gotten from the API requests in the effects.

When I use the selectors in my home.component.ts I get this output:

```
homepage.component - global state - books is
["", {…}, 4, true, …]
0: ""
1: Object
2: 4
3: true
4: ""

homepage.component - global state - pokemon is
["", {…}, 4, true, …]
0: ""
1: Object
2: 4
3: true
4: ""
```

But the effects API call is working.

**I have set up an online example:** [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tclk5v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fhomepage%2Fhomepage.component.ts)

Just uncomment the "// Global State Calls Do Not Work" section

Any help appreciated! I am a little lost.

Cheers!

Edit:

I have fixed the selector and I wasn't doing anything with the booksLoaded action.

The new error is:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer> | ((value: BooksState) => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(res: Book[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer> | ((value: BooksState) => void) | undefined'.

Makes me think the "Bookstate extends Book" in book.reducer isn't doing what I think it's doing...

Comment: You don't have any global state for the array of books/pokemon on these feature states. Your selector `Object.values(state.books)` is just getting the feature state with status / dataLoaded / errorMsg. No data is from your array is being saved to state

Comment: There is so much wrong in the stackblitz. Why does a BookState extend a Book? A BookState should yield an array of books. You don't even use the books array from the action in your reducer. Same respectively for pokemon. You can use the browsers dev tools to inspect your state before trying to display it. You will see you fail beforehand.

Comment: The reason a BookState extends a book is I want the book state to have everything the book model does but with some state-specific variables like status, loading, errorMsg

Comment: I have made some changes. I actually think Moxxi was onto something maybe the BookState extends Book is a problem after all...

Answer (score 1):

The `selectBooks` selector doesn't return an array of Books, it's just returning a single book.
If you need this to be an array, you need to store an array of books in the reducer.

Comment: You are right! How would I create one? use map?